# Bitbucket REST API query fails with python but succeed with curl

Tags: python, curl, python-requests, bitbucket

I'm trying to retrieve information from bitbucket using REST API. If I run the query using **curl** it succeeds.

```
C:\>curl -vv -k --header "Authorization: Bearer %TOKEN%" https://bitbucket.cicd/rest/api/1.0/projects/%OWNER%/repos/%PROJECT%/raw/%LOCATION%?at=%COMMIT%
*   Trying 10.<....>:443...
* Connected to bitbucket.cicd (10.<....>) port 443 (#0)
* schannel: disabled automatic use of client certificate
* ALPN: offers http/1.1
* ALPN: server did not agree on a protocol. Uses default.
* using HTTP/1.x
> GET /rest/api/1.0/projects/<.....> HTTP/1.1
> Host: bitbucket.cicd
> User-Agent: curl/8.0.1
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Bearer <token>
>
* schannel: failed to decrypt data, need more data
< HTTP/1.1 200
< x-arequestid: *<....>
< set-cookie: BITBUCKETSESSIONID=<....>; Max-Age=1209600; Expires=Sat, 15 Jul 2023 15:25:03 GMT; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
< x-auserid: <....>
< x-ausername: <....>
< x-asessionid: <....>
< cache-control: private, no-cache
< pragma: no-cache
< cache-control: no-cache, no-transform
< vary: x-ausername,x-auserid,cookie,accept-encoding
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
< content-disposition: attachment; filename="<....>"; filename*=UTF-8''<....>
< content-type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
< content-length: 3916
< date: Sat, 01 Jul 2023 15:25:02 GMT
<
<...file content...>
* Connection #0 to host bitbucket.cicd left intact
```

However, I want to do the exact same thing using **python** and it fails

```
import requests

TOKEN = '<token>'
OWNER = '<owner>'
PROJECT = '<project>'
LOCATION = '<location>'
COMMIT = '<commit>'

headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {TOKEN}'
    }

url = f'https://bitbucket.cicd/rest/api/1.0/projects/{OWNER}/repos/{PROJECT}/raw/{LOCATION}?at={COMMIT}'
response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers, verify=False)
print(response)
```

The response is:

```
response.status_code: 401
response._content: b'{"errors":[{"context":null,"message":"Authentication failed. Please check your credentials and try again.","exceptionName":"com.atlassian.bitbucket.auth.IncorrectPasswordAuthenticationException"}]}'
```

Can someone explain to me why?

Thanks in advance,
-Uri

Answer (score 0):

After some additional searching and experimentation I found the answer.

```
import requests
import requests.auth

TOKEN = '<token>'
USER = '<user>'
OWNER = '<opwner>'
PROJECT = '<repo>'
LOCATION = '<path>'
COMMIT = '<commit>'

auth = requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth(USER, TOKEN)
url = f'https://bitbucket.cicd.dc/rest/api/1.0/projects/{OWNER}/repos/{PROJECT}/raw/{LOCATION}?at={COMMIT}'
response = requests.get(url=url, auth=auth, verify=False)
print(response)
```

Note that *<user>* value is not the user email but the account name.